# Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement Don't know how to fix

Tags: php, mysql

So i have encountered this error trying to defend my login system from sql injection. I do not know why my system says my prepared statement is not producing enough variables so i would like some help with this.

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = '$myusername' and 
password = '$mypassword'"); if (!$sql) 
    {
        echo "failed to run";
    } 
    else 
    {
        $sql->bind_param('ss',$_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
        $sql->bind_result($myusername, $mypassword);
        $sql->execute();
        $sql->fetch();
    }
```

Comment: You need to read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: The sql statement has variables directly embedded rather than placeholders ( `?` ) - change the embedded variables (`$myusername` & `$mypassword` ) for placeholders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Statement is not a prepared Statement. A prepared Statement uses placeholder where the values are bind to:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = ? and 
password = ?");
```

For more informations about prepared Statements in php read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: If i could ask one more thing. i still get an error after it saying Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given with my $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql) any ideas why?

Comment: @Daynie you have to call `$sql->execute();` to execute the prepared Statement, not `mysqli_query`

Comment: I already executed it though this is a different portion of the code if (!$sql) 
  {
   echo "failed to run";
  } 
  else 
  {
   $sql->bind_param('ss',$_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
   $sql->bind_result($id);
   $sql->execute();
   $sql->fetch();
  
  }
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql)
     or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

      $active = $row['active'];
      
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

Comment: @Daynie Do not mix the ways you call the Statement. in your case $SQL is not a string it is a prepared statement